# TV channel in C# and I'm using Vlc API. When the video start and its duration is 3:00 minutes and I want to go to 1:30 this time what should I do?

Tags: c#

That's the code of the Button I'm using to go to that time. I've tried some methods or events but none of them worked for me.

I want to give input from textbox and when I click Button go the video should go to that time.

```
private void btn_go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        frm.vlc.input.time = int.Parse(txt_time.Text); //this is giving the length of video in textbox         
       // frm.vlc.MediaPlayerPositionChanged += txt_time.Text.ToString();
       // TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(txt_time.Text));
        //MessageBox.Show(span.ToString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which library you are using but you can set the "Position" property of the vlc control in you application.

More, I suggest you to use [this](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet) library. You can start from [here](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/wiki/Getting-started) for more details.

Comment: you can many samples in the same git hub repo. check https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/tree/develop/src/Samples